# jQuery :not(:first) not working in IE8, but does in FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery-selectors

$('.divMapTab:not(:first)').each(...

I've got 2 divs on my page, both with class of divMapTab.  In FF and Chrome, the code above only selects the 2nd instance of divMapTab, but in IE it selects them both.

Am I missing a subtlety in how the :not or :first keywords work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IE does not support the CSS :not selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/not.html) which this method relies on.  Instead try:

```
$('.divMapTab').not().first().each(...
```

Answer (score 2):

The ".not().first().each(" solution did not work in my case.

I had to qualify more my ":first" selector repeating the class name ".panneau":

> $(".panneau:not(.panneau:first)").hide();

It's a [behavior that won't be fixed](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6838) by jQuery.